# JS/JQuery/PHP - How to echo errors on form validate failure, and jump to div on success?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a fixed-position form that can be scrolled out onto the document and filled out anywhere on the page. If they fail to fill out the form properly, the errors are currently echod out onto the form, which is the intended design for that aspect. What I don't currently know how to do is, if the form is completed and `$errors[]` is empty, to use jQuery `scrollTop()` to jump down to the bottom.

Could anyone help me out with this? Current javascript involved is:

```
$("#A_FORM_submit_button").click(function() {
    $("#FORM_A").submit( function () {    
    $.post(
        'ajax/FORM_A_processing.php',
         $(this).serialize(),
         function(data){
             $("#A_errors_").html(data);
         }
    );
    return false;   
    }); 
});
```

The PHP involved is simply

```
if (!empty($errors)){
    // echo errors
} else { // echo success message}  <-- would like to jump to div as well
```

edit-- for clarity: not looking to make the page jump happen in the php file, so much as return a value for the jq $.post function to check and then perform an if/else

Comment: You cannot do what you are trying to do. Apache has finished serving the page, the PHP cannot be run again. You are trying to mix server side and client side code. Use a jQuery `.done` after your `.post`

Comment: I don't think I need the PHP to be run again. Is there a way to return a value back to the javascript function that calls this .php page, and then based on the return value, it executes one piece of code or another, in the $.post code?

Comment: Take a look at the `jquery .post` function and it's ability for `.done`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be jumping the gun here but I believe your design is wrong which is why you are running into this problem.

The ideal way of handling form validation is to validate forms via Javascript and when users enter in their information you immediately show some indicator to ask them to correct it. As long as the validation is incorrect, you should not be accepting a form request or making any AJAX calls.

In the off-chance that they do successfully send the data, you should be doing a validation check via PHP as well which, if failed, would redirect to the original page with the form. From there you could do whatever error handling you want but ideally you would retain the information they entered and indicate why it was wrong (Javascript should catch this but I guess if it gets here the user might have JS off or your validation logic might be wrong)

If I understand correctly, it seems like you are doing your error handling with Javascript (that's fine) but showing the error via PHP. As Hydra IO said don't confuse client-side and server side. Make them handle what they need to handle.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The reason why I did error checking in PHP is because the server requests are not going to be large so efficiency is not a huge factor in here, and secondly it seemed (at the time) easier to me to just echo errors into a div in PHP rather than JS, but I'm sure it's doable in JS as well... I just had this association of "JS error checking -> alerts -> ugly" which is probably just an oversimplification. That said, my main issue I think is unaffected by this, because upon success I *still* need to send out an email and jump down to a div.

Comment: Yeah -- if I was unclear, I do see that I can do that. Ah actually I see a potential solution now, although if there's still a way to return a value from PHP to the jquery $.post call I'd love to learn how that's possible. If that's impossible, some more confirmation would be nice too. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

@aug described the scenario very clearly.

In code it translates in something like this

```
$('form').submit(function(){

    form_data = $(this).serialize();

    if(!validate(form_data))
    {
        // deal with validation, show error messages

        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        // Submit form, either via Ajax $.post() or by just returning TRUE
    }
});
```

The `validate()` function is up to you to work out.